# How do I intercept packages in a Facebook application?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, facebook, certificate-pinning, fiddler

I can not listen to HTTPS traffic in the Facebook application through Fiddler and Burp. SSL-Pinning is disabled through SLL Kill Switch 2 (other applications such as Twitter, Snapchat with SSL-Pinning are well-audible) and Mobile Assistant (for Burp). Web-version of Facebook is working fine, HTTPS-traffic is successfully listened.

I suspect that a possible problem lies in some authentication service that runs separately from the main application, as described in this article:

https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2013/08/20/intercepting-the-app-stores-traffic-on-ios/

For example, Twitter and Facebook use the accountsd service, which is responsible for integrating with these applications. But, firstly in the new versions of Kill Switch, this problem is solved, and secondly, I tried to perform the kill of this process manually, but does not work with Facebook.

How can I solve this problem of intercepting packets in a Facebook application?